# segmentation fault while allocating dynamically 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am pretty sure people who knows their ways with pointers will get mad at me since it will seems to be an already answered question but I couldn't understand what I am doing wrong with this triple pointer... So I am apologizing in advance....

I am trying to dynamically allocate a 2d array through this function as such :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float **alloctab(int dim1, int dim2) {
    float **ptr;

    ptr = malloc(dim1*sizeof(float *));
    if (ptr != NULL) {
    int i, taille_ligne = dim2*sizeof(float);
    float *tmp = malloc(dim1*taille_ligne);
    if (tmp != NULL) {
        for (i=0; i<dim1; i++) {
        ptr[i] = tmp;
        tmp += dim2;
        }
    }
    else
    ptr = NULL;
    }
    return(ptr);
}

int call_alloc(float ***ptr, int d1,int d2)
{
    int i,j;
    *ptr = alloctab(d1,d2);

    for (i=0;i<d1;i++)
    for (j=0;j<d2;j++)
        {
        *ptr[i][j]=(float)i+(float)j;
        printf("ptr[%d][%d]=%f\n",i,j,*ptr[i][j]);
        }
    return 0;
} 

int main() 
{
    float ***tab = NULL;
    int d1=6,d2=8;
    call_alloc(tab,d1,d2);
    return 0;
}
```

And of course I am getting a segmentation fault while using it, although the compiler in -Wall mode does not complain about anything...

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:.

1. `*ptr[i][j]` is not the same as `(*ptr)[i][j]`
2. `float ***tab = NULL; call_alloc(tab,d1,d2);` pass a NULL-pointer to  function `call_alloc`

Adapt your code like this:

```
int call_alloc(float ***ptr, int d1,int d2)
{
    int i,j;
    *ptr = alloctab(d1,d2);

    for (i=0;i<d1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<d2;j++)
        {
            (*ptr)[i][j]=(float)i+(float)j;
         // ^    ^
            printf("ptr[%d][%d]=%f\n",i,j,(*ptr)[i][j]);
                                       // ^    ^ 
        }
    }
    return 0;
} 

int testmain() 
{
    float **tab = NULL;
       // ^^
    int d1=6,d2=8;
    call_alloc(&tab,d1,d2);
            // ^
    return 0;
}
```

Note your code does not `free` the memory.

Answer (score -1):

- Just replace this piece of your code with below code,

  ```
  int call_alloc(float **ptr, int d1,int d2)
  {
     int i,j;
     ptr = alloctab(d1,d2);

     for (i=0;i<d1;i++)
    for (j=0;j<d2;j++)
    {
       ptr[i][j]=(float)i+(float)j;
       printf("ptr[%d][%d]=%f\n",i,j,ptr[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  int main()
  {
     float **tab = NULL;
     int d1=6,d2=8;
     call_alloc(tab,d1,d2);
     return 0;
  }
  ```